# How do I mock Pyramid's `request.matched_route` object?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyramid

I'm writing unit tests for my project that uses [Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid//en/latest/index.html). What I've done so far is add data and attributes manually to the requests. For example setting an id in the route:

```
request = testing.DummyRequest()
request.matchdict['id'] = 19
```

One of my views has multiple routes attached to it, and I determine the route with `request.matched_route.name`.

Now when I try to manually set the route like:

```
request.matched_route.name = 'one_of_my_routes'
```

or

```
request.matched_route = {'name': 'one_of_my_routes'}
```

I get errors. What is the correct way to test this using Python unit tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this isn't Javascript. You can't make a dictionary and expect to use the dot operator on it. So that's why #2 doesn't work. #1 is likely related to the fact that you need to create each object in the chain. `request` only has a `matched_route` property if a route matches so you'll need to create that object.

```
class DummyRoute(object):
    name = 'one_of_my_routes'

request.matched_route = DummyRoute()
```